# Tabular: columnwidth of e.g. 3cm, but numprint column

Tags: tables, numprint

The [numprint package](https://ctan.org/pkg/numprint) provides some things I need: Rounding after the decimal sign, adding missing zeros, german thousand- and decimalseparator.

But I'd like to have a column with numbers formatted by numprint having a certain width, let's say 3 cm.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{numprint, array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{N{3}{2}}
  {Text}\\
  123.45\\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

How can I define a tabular column like N, but with the character as well as if it were `p{3cm}`?

Comment: with `siunitx` this is easy to achieve ...

Comment: @Zarko I'd be interested to see that, if you'd like to drop some lines as an answer.

Comment: i will do this late afternoon. now i go on the way (to home) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{numprint}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|N{3}{2}|}
  {\makebox[3cm]{Text}}\\
  123.45\\
  12.3\\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

let me expand my comment (*with `siunitx` this is easy*) to an answer ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|S[table-column-width=30mm,
                   table-format=3.2,
                   output-decimal-marker={,}]|
                }
{Text}      \\
  123.45    \\
   12.3     \\
\end{tabular}    
\end{document}
```

[image]